# Synchronize request responsein java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request

I have some services that provide information at different times but I would like some services to provide all the answers at the same time despite being different services.

I am using java 11 with spring boot and using api rest I will leave below the example of one of the services

```
@GetMapping(value = "/caract/opcoes/acoes/disponiveis")
public ResponseEntity<List<GroupByData>> getDatasCaractOpcoesAcoesDisponiveis() {
    List<GroupByData> result = caractOpcoesAcoesServico.findGroupByIdentityRptDt();
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<GroupByData>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<GroupByData>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How can I release the response of several request that are released at different times only after everyone is ready?

Comment: Could you explain better the part of "release the response of several request" ?

Comment: services release information at different time wanted to release information only when everyone is ok

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this. First I will explain the nice way which is reactive and webflux.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/anothertest")
public Mono<String> rest() {
    log.info("request number " + reqCounter++);
    CompletableFuture<String> stringCompletableFuture = sendRequestWithJavaHttpClient().thenApply(x -> "test: " + x);
    Duration between = Duration.between(
            LocalTime.now(),
            LocalTime.parse("14:01:00")// I am assuming there is a time we send data back 
    );
    return Mono.first(Mono.delay(between)).then(Mono.fromFuture(stringCompletableFuture));
}

private CompletableFuture<String> sendRequestWithJavaHttpClient() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        // do some logic here
        return "hello world.";
    });
}
```

As we say to first mono to delay the response it will wait until the time comes and do the function call after. This is the nice way because with this way there is no blocking on response. all clients will need to wait. you will need to use webflux of spring.

The second and not cool way is to block the thread. this one uses spring mvc

```
@GetMapping(value = "/caract/opcoes/acoes/disponiveis*")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getDatasCaractOpcoesAcoesDisponiveis() throws Exception {
    log.info("request number " + reqCounter++);
    Duration between = Duration.between(
            LocalTime.now(),
            LocalTime.parse("14:10:00")
    );
    log.info("will sleep "+between.toMillis());
    Thread.sleep(between.toMillis());
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>("hello world", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This will block the server thread until the time comes. problem about this is the thread count of tomcat. the default value is 200, therefore, your application can have max 200 requests and after that tomcat can not take any more connections. You can increase it by changing server.tomcat.max-threads=500 in the application.properties

you can find running example code here https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/response-wait-methods

If you ask my opinion about these two ways is not nice from a design point of view because clients should not wait. I would go with responding NOK until the time comes. and if time is good just respond to the real result. this way client-side can request as much as they want without load. and server-side won't have any load because nothing is blocked.